# RewriteRule - only two directories and a file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite URLs through .htaccess and what I want is that a rule be taken into account only if the URL is like *"www.mysite.com/basedir/directory/file.htm"*.
I don't want *"www.mysite.com/basedir/file.htm"* or *"www.mysite.com/basedir/directory/directory/file.htm"*, I want the exact described structure. At the moment I am trying to do it with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(basedir)/([^/\.]+)/(.*)\.(htm)$    /template.php?&page=$3   [L]
```

but it doesn't work. It accepts any number of directories after basedir.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second match area needs to have a character exclusion like the first:

```
RewriteRule ^(basedir)/([^/\.]+)/([^/]*)\.(htm)$    /template.php?&page=$3   [L]
```

That way you don't allow additional slashes to be matched, only the two explicit slashes earlier in the pattern.

Also, what exactly are you trying to match with `$3`? You only need to use parentheses around things that you need to match. If `$3` is supposed to match `file.htm`, then you could instead write:

```
RewriteRule ^basedir/[^/\.]+/([^/]*\.htm)$    /template.php?&page=$1   [L]
```

or if it should just match "file" then:

```
RewriteRule ^basedir/[^/\.]+/([^/]*)\.htm$    /template.php?&page=$1   [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. I will remove parentheses from what I don't need.